# How to add button map.openInfoWindow using Google Maps in mobile Flex project?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, apache-flex, google-maps-api-3, flex4.5

[image]

I am developing map application in mobile Flex project. In this mobile Flex project I am using Google Maps in this application. I am generating google map and zoom in,zoom out controls and I am click the map open windows and this window display lat,lon details.

I am using this code for map info window:

```
map.openInfoWindow(event.latLng,new InfoWindowOptions({title: " Tap on button ",content:"Lat and Lan"+rtitle.toString()}));
```

In this window, how can add the button and button click event also?